# Fatal error: Call to a member function, on a non-object, codeigniter controller

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

Here's my controller profileinfo.php

```
<?php
class Profileinfo extends CI_Controller {

    function index()
    {

        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
        $this->load->model('aluminsert','', TRUE);
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('branch', 'Bramch', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('academicinterest', 'Academic Interest', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('internshipdetail', 'Internship Details', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('interest_hobbies', 'Interest and hobbies', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('personalblog', 'Personal Blog', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('facebookprofile', 'Facebook Profile', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('linkedinprofile', 'Linkedin Profile', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('homecity', 'Home city', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('country', 'country', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('higherdegree', 'Higher Degree', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('collegeofeducation', 'College of Education', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('officialemail', 'Official Email', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('careerinterests', 'Career Interest', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('presentemployer', 'Present Employer', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('presentjob', 'Present Job', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('previousemployer', 'Previous Employee', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('startupname', 'Startup Name', 'required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $this->load->view('alumprofile');

        }
        else
        {
            $alumdata = array(
            'Name' => $this->input->post('name'),
            'Branch' => $this->input->post('branch'),
            'Academic Interest' => $this->input->post('academicinterest'),
            'Internship Details' => $this->input->post('internshipdetail'),
            'Interest and hobbies' => $this->input->post('interest_hobbies'),
            'personalblog' => $this->input->post('personalblog'),
            'Facebook profile' => $this->input->post('facebookprofile'),
            'Linkedin profile' => $this->input->post('linkedinprofile'),
            'Home city' => $this->input->post('homecity'),
            'country' => $this->input->post('country'),
            'Higher Degree' => $this->input->post('higherdegree'),
            'College of Education' => $this->input->post('collegeofeducation'),
            'Official Email' => $this->input->post('officialmail'),
            'Career Interest' => $this->input->post('careerinterests'),
            'Present Employer' => $this->input->post('presentemployer'),
            'Present Job' => $this->input->post('presentjob'),
            'Previous Employee' => $this->input->post('previousemployer'),
            'Startup Name' => $this->input->post('startupname'),
            );
            // Transfering Data To Model
            $this->insert->alum_insert($alumdata);
            $this->load->view('registration_success');
        }
    }
}
?>
```

and here's is my model aluminsert.php

```
<?php
class Aluminsert extends CI_Model{
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    function alum_insert($alumdata){

        $this->db->insert('user_detail', $alumdata);
    }
}
?>
```

form validation is working and after submitting the form, the error shown is:
Fatal error: Call to a member function alum_insert() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\ci\application\controllers\profileinfo.php on line 61

Comment: model name is `aluminsert` not `insert` it should be `$this->alum_insert->alum_insert($alumdata);`

Comment: @karanthakkar almost there. `$this->aluminsert->alum_insert($alumdata)`

Comment: @MarioCesar yeah, my bad a typo ;)

Answer (score 0):

The error lies in the code below. You are trying to call a method from the 'insert' class which in this case does not exist in your model.

```
$this->insert->alum_insert($alumdata);
$this->load->view('registration_success');
```

Your Model is called 'Aluminsert' and the method you are using to insert is called 'alum_insert' so you should rather do this.

```
$this->aluminsert->alum_insert($alumdata);
$this->load->view('registration_success');
```

Answer (score -1):

In codeigniter we need to load the database. So there are two ways

1. Either you can autoload it or
2. Load where ever you need it.

In **autoload.php**,you have to write the below line.

`$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');`

OR

In other manner you can also load in following manner :-

`$this->load->database();`

Surely it will help you.

Comment: How is this related to the question?